# Rank of a matrix plus a number

Tags: matrix-rank

Suppose to have a symmetric matrix $A$ with rank equal to $a$. Now let
$$
A_1 = A + \frac{x}{2}
$$

such that $x$ is a real number different from 0.

Is it always true that rank of $A_1 = a+1$? Can you prove that?
In which case this will be true?

Comment: What does it mean to add a real number to a matrix?

Comment: How do you add a real number to a matrix? And why would the rank change if $x = 0$, since then $A = A_1$?

Comment: Are you adding a real number to a matrix?  How are you doing that?

Comment: Add a real number it means to add the same quantity (x/2) to all the entries in the matrix A

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, its premise seems incorrect. For counterexample, let $A$ be the 2x2 identity matrix, whose rank is $a=2$. The rank of $A_1$ in that case (given suitable restrictions such as that $x\neq 0$ and the like) is not $a+1$ but $a$.

Comment: "To add the same quantity ... to *all* entries?" That's odd. I would have expected it to add the quantity along the main diagonal only. Regrettably, it may be that your question is confused.

Comment: @thb: Actually before the clarification, given the claim, I thought maybe the direct sum was meant (i.e. adding the value as extra diagonal element, with the corresponding non-diagonal elements zero); because then for $x\ne 0$ the claim would have been true.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong.

Take any *invertible* symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, hence of maximal rank $n$; since $A+\frac x2$ has the same size, it cannot have a rank larger than that of $A$.

Moreover, if all entries of $A$ were equal to $-\frac x2$, then rk$(A)$ would be $1$ and rk$(A+\frac x2)$ would be $0$. So you see that the rank can decrease as well.